# Этимология слова "робость"

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Робость — неуверенность, несмелость. Мне интересно, однокоренное ли это слово со словом "работа" (учитывая чередование в корне букв А и О)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В известном смысле - да. Но на весьма древнем, праславянском и индоевропейском уровне.

> Робость Происходит от прил. робкий, далее из слав. роб «раб, невольник», сюда же ребёнок. Ср. др.-инд. arbhakás, árbhagas «маленький, слабый, молодой», árbhas – то же. Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера;

(Вики)

Работа и раб тоже связаны

> Происходит от праслав. формы *orbota, от которой в числе прочего произошли: древнерусск. робота «работа, рабство, неволя», ст.-слав. работа.

Там же.

Так что робость и работа можно считать "многоюроднвми" кузенами. 
Сейчас это связь давно перестала ощущаться носителями языка.

Answer (score 4):

Робкий буквально — "по своему поведению подобный ребенку (робу)".

Comment: Ребенок --> *робя*

Answer (score 1):

Также согласен - от РеБеНка  у семит. БН - сын.отросль.